# How to create an extended User Object in Django?

Tags: python, django

I created a model `ExtendedUser` to extend the `User` Django built-in model class using the approach described in the official documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model
so that I can benefit from the existing authentication features provided by Django.
That works all fine however I wonder now, whenever I want to create a new `ExtendedUser`, that means for every `ExtendedUser`, I also need to create an original `User` to fullfill the one-to-one relationship?

Or what else does it mean the following:

> Assuming an existing Employee Fred Smith who **has both a User and Employee model**, you can access the related information using Django’s
> standard related model conventions[...]

In a script to create objects, would this mean the following:

```
u1 = User.objects.create_user(username="u_1", email="u_1@abc.com", password="pw_u_1")   
ext_u_1 = ExtendedUser.objects.create(id=u1.id, user=u1, prop_1="XYZ")
```

where

```
class ExtendedUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, ...)
    # More properties...
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you extend using OneToOne field, it will require to create both objects i.e. User as well as ExtendedUser to fulfil the one to one relationship.

But I would suggest to not use OneToOne field instead override the AbstractUser model provided by Django to create the ExtendedUserModel, even if you don't need anything extra in ExtendedUserModel now. It will help you to add any new fields, methods easily to your user model in future as well as you won't be needed to create two object for a single User.

Same has been suggested in Django docs as well. Reference:- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project

Comment: cool, i guess I ended up in the "Extending" Section because the project is already started. But i can still easily adjust that.